# Is there a fully sentient android race in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, androids

Aside from Commander Data and Lore being the only android we have seen (and some earlier prototypes), and since the Borg do not qualify as being androids, are there any fully sentient android race in Star Trek Universe, either in Canon or non-Canon?

Comment: Data also has a sentient brother named [Lore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lore_(Star_Trek)#Lore).

Comment: Sorry, I knew that. I was just referring if a race existed. :)

Comment: There's one later Soong-type android that no one - not even the ship's scanners - could differentiate from a human.  Only Data had any suspicions.  At least until her arm broke off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition of [artificial life](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) is a hot button topic in the Federation. Some people see them merely as tools, while others see them as full fledged life forms. However, to answer your question, there are a couple of example of groups of androids that have been seen in Star trek. Whether they qualify as sentient races, however, is a question for the philosophers. Note that Data is not the only [Soong type](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Soong-type_android) android we see.

Memory-Alpha as lists of self-aware [machines](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Self-aware_machines) and [programs](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Self-aware_programs), but there are a few notable examples that come to my mind.

- the [Mudd Androids](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Mudd_androids) (questionable sentience)
- the [Automated Personnel Units](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Automated_Personnel_Unit) (questionable sentience)
- [Ruk](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ruk) (and the Exo III androids)
- [Rayna Kapec](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rayna_Kapec)
- any [Soong type](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Soong-type_android) android

Special mentions (not androids, but sentient artificial life nonetheless).

- the [Emergency Medical Holographic Program](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Emergency_Medical_Holographic_program)
- [James Moriartiy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/James_Moriarty_%28hologram%29)
- [V'Ger](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/V%27Ger)

Comment: And all the holograms ("photonic life-forms") of the [Lokirrim](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Lokirrim), they're as sentient - if not moreso - than Moriarty

Comment: Oh, and the [Exocomps](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Exocomp), once each one achieves it

Comment: @Izkata Do we ever meet a Lokirrim photonic life form?

Comment: Wait, not Lokirrim.  I was looking for a different VOY episode and got the two confused.  There was group of renegade holograms that stole a ship and tried to convert the Doctor in one of the episodes...  _EDIT:_ VOY 7x09/7x10, [Flesh and Blood](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Flesh_and_Blood_(episode)), whereas the Lokirrim was VOY 7x07, [Body and Soul](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Body_and_Soul_(episode)).  _Flesh and Blood_ is fairly significant in that, like Moriarty, they came from Federation technology.

Comment: It seems that Federation technology is quite good at spawning unintended artificial life.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[Memory Alpha has a full list](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Android), including:

- *Voyager: "Prototype"* had  **Automated Personnel Units**
- **Exo III** type androids (*TOS: "What Are Little Girls Made Of?*)

---

For non-canon, the lists is at [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Android), and includes:

- [Galor IV androids](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Galor_IV)