# Androids in the 24th century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, androids

There seems to be a considerable lack of androids in the 24th century aside from Soong-type androids. We do, however see that the area of robotics still is progressing, especially at the Daystrom intitute.

My question is: **Aside from *Soong-type* androids, what are the other androids we see (in TNG, DS9 and VOY) and who created them?**

Comment: It seems that they've went a different direction with their technology and chose instead to develop and rely on holograms more than robotics.

Comment: Though not an exact duplicate, here's a similar question you can look at for research; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/is-there-a-fully-sentient-android-race-in-star-trek?rq=1

Comment: I thought there might be some buried nugget or loose thread sticking up there that could be teased out to get closer to a comprehensive answer here. Not above taking advantage of their good research :-) I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from Soong-type androids, the only other encounter mentioned in Memory Alpha in the 24th Century are the [Automated Personnel Units](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Automated_Personnel_Unit) encountered by Voyager, but even those were made in the 23rd century.

[image: An Automated Personnel Unit]

Outside canon though:

- in the TNG novel *[Immortal Coil](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Immortal_Coil)*, Dr Soong along with Graves and
  Vaslovik journeyed to Exo III where they released the androids from
  stasis who were referred to in TOS *What are little girls made of?*
- 21st Century Earth android imposters who were used for assassinations are referenced in the TNG novel *[The Buried Age](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Buried_Age)*
- Klingon and Romulan androids, less advanced than the Soong-type androids, in an alternate universe int he TNG novel *[Brave New World](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Brave_New_World)*
- [Kisaria](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/Kisaria) from [Dimensional Prophecy of Zohar](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/Dimensional_Prophecy_of_Zohar)
- [Bishop](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/Dimensional_Prophecy_of_Zohar) from [Star Trek: Voyager - Dark Realm](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_-_Dark_Realm)

and, going a bit beyond the scope of the question for interest's sake:

> By the 30th century, androids were in even wider use in the
> Federation, even staffing entire facilities. Sometime after this
> century, a division in android types lead to a heavy war that reduced
> the human population significantly. (Star Trek: Returner, Star Trek:
> Rise of the Machines, Star Trek: Phoenix-X: "Vitality")

([Source](https://stexpanded.fandom.com/wiki/Android))

Comment: Did any of the non-canon novels/ comic books mention the androids of Leticia (Mudd's Planet) after James and Judy Blish's novella? They would certainly still have existed by the 24th century, and Dr McCoy announced his intention to sponsor them for membership in the Federation.